# Cannot figure out how to compute a computed field in Lightswitch

Tags: linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-lightswitch, computed-field

I have the following problem - I would like to compute a field in my database based on a simple query and division. 
First a bit of info about my database structure:

`|WorkingUnits|-1---------n-|Materials|`
e.i One-to-Many relation between WU and Materials.

This is the two tables and the relation between them. In the WorkingUnits table, I have a computed field called WUAmount. Also each Working Unit has a 'Price'. Same goes for the Materials - each of them has a 'Price'. 
In the end what I would like to achive is to sum up all the prices of all Materials assigned to a particular Working Unit and divide that by the price of the Working Unit itself.

What I am trying to do so far is the following:

```
    partial void WUAmount_Compute(ref decimal result)
    {
        //decimal amount = 0;
        IDataServiceQueryable<WorkingUnit> query;
        query = from WorkingUnit in this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.WorkingUnits
                where WorkingUnit.Materials != null
                select WorkingUnit;

        foreach (WorkingUnit detail in query)
        {
            result = this.WUPrice / (result + detail.Materials.Sum(s => s.Price).Value);
        }
}
```

But I get an Inner Exception:

```
Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1'.
Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.
```

I am fairly new to Lightswitch and LINQ and cannot figure this yet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, all you should need is:

```
partial void WUAmount_Compute(ref decimal result)
{
   result = (this.Materials.Sum(x => x.Price) / this.WUPrice);
}
```

Comment: Exactly :) I manged to figure this out by myself, but could not post and approve my own answer due to "not enough points".
Thank you for the response though. It was much more trivial than expected. Hope it might help someone else as well :)

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, I hope it helps someone else too. :-)